# Kohana ORM limit column size

Tags: php, kohana

How can I limit the size of column value returned by ORM. 
I have a field having type long text. 
I want ORM only to fetch starting 100 value, 
how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a dummy field (like in your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659291/adding-dummy-column-in-kohana-orm)) with a shortened value? You can use Kohana's `Text::limit_chars()` or `Text::limit_words()` for it.

Comment: but I have a question about this approach . 
this will load full text from the database.
Not only starting 100 chars. 
Will it not more costly in comparison of  just loading starting x char.

Comment: ORM by default will load all columns from table. But you can create a view (in DB) with shortened value and use it in ORM model.

Comment: one doubt 
on the following link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982570/kohana-v3-1-0-orm-ignored-columns-now-that-its-gone-what-should-i-do-instea
It seems that in v3.1.0 of Kohana's ORM that the _ignored_columns property has been removed.
is it ?

Comment: Well, just create a public property in your model and store value in it ;) But note that you will need to modify `__get()` code from my previous answer as you dont use `$this->_object`.

Comment: than $this->_object will be replaced by ?

Comment: I mean how I can check value is set or not ?
and set that value

Comment: Probably you should define it as protected (`protected $_short_text`), so you can use `__get()` method. Just check `isset($this->_short_text)` and set it as `$this->_short_text = Text::limit_chars($this->text, ...)`.